# I am trying to solve this problem but getting a run time error due to segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays

I used scanf to get inputs for 3 variables but I believe it crashes when it gets only 2 integers as input, Can someone suggest a better way to scan all 3 variables

Question:

You are hired to offer phone number look up service for a company's internal network. The company has N employees with employee ID 0 to N−1. Your job is to when asked for the phone number for employee i, output that person's number on screen.

In addition, you are also being asked to update the directory. Aside from enquiries, your boss may ask you to update an employee's number from time to time, and you should do so.

Input Specification
The first line will contain two integers N and M (1

The following N lines will each contain a single integer P (1

Then, the next M lines will each contain first an integer t (t∈0,1) indicating the request type.

If t is 0, then it will be followed by a query for phone number by a single integer, which is the employee's ID.

If t is 1, then it will be followed by an employee ID in integer i, then another integer k with the new phone number.

Output Specification
There should be M lines in your output, each an integer for the phone number that is asked.

Should the query ask for an employee not on the directory (P>N−1), output No entry.

Should the query ask you to update a phone number, output New number for i is k, where i is the employee ID and k the new number.

**Sample Input 1**

```
5 5
1024
2048
7789
4321
42
0 2
0 7
0 3
1 2 1111
0 2
```

**Sample Output 1**

```
7789
No entry
3
New number for 2 is 1111
1111
```

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  int n, m, t, i, k;
  scanf("%d %d \n", & n, & m);
  int a[n];
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    scanf("%d\n", & a[j]);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d\n", & t, & i, & k);

    if (t == 1) {
      if (i > n - 1) printf("No entry\n");
      else {
        a[i] = k;
        printf("New number for %d is %d\n", i, k);
      }
    } else if (t == 0 && i > n - 1) printf("No entry\n");

    else printf("%d\n", a[i]);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[n];` is invalid C++ using VLA extension, use `std::vector` instead

Comment: Suggestion: Make life easier on yourself and give variables descriptive names. Sure, this slows you down typing longer names, but you more than make that back as soon as you have to debug.

Comment: I suspect scanf("%d %d %d\n", & t, & i, & k); crashing on lines that have only 2 integers. .......... Agree with the tag change this is C. And I also agree there are some issues with this assignment (job?). Consider user requirements: a phone list you want to store on file somewhere.

Comment: Please [edit] your question's tags to clarify whether you are using C or C++. It looks like you are writing C++ code, but you are using C features, like variable-length arrays (VLAs). The mixing of these could be causing issues. In order to help you, we need to know exactly what compiler you're using and what flags you're passing to it. Do you intend to be writing C or C++?

Comment: @CodyGray the first line `#include <cstdio>` shows that the author uses C++. For sure this C++ is far from being perfect, but the actual problem is not language related. The problem can be found just from the question description.

Comment: Reads like code golf or perhaps Fortran77.

Comment: @Goodies can you suggest something so that it can also accept lines with only two integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading 3 values at a time:

```
scanf("%d %d %d\n", & t, & i, & k);
```

but the actual number of integers depends on the value of `t`. This means that for the sample input the first time you read these data the values for (t, i, k) would be (0, 2, 0). The next read is surprisingly (7, 0, 3), and the program is not prepared to the `t = 7`. You may run into a situation when the value for `k` would be read into `i`, the value of `t` would be neither 0 not 1. In this case your program would execute the last `else` branch:

```
printf("%d\n", a[i]);
```

The value for `k` may be outside of the range, that would lead to segmentation fault.

How to fix the problem? First, you need to split reading the `t` and the rest of the values:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &t);

        if (t == 1) {
            // Read 2 values and implement the logic for t == 1
        }
        else if (t == 0) {
            // Read just 1 value and implement the logic for t == 0
        }
        else {
            printf("Input error! Wrong value of t. t == &d\n", t);
        }
    }
```

Next, read the `scanf` family documentation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and study how the function uses the format string. Hint: it ignores whitespaces.

Even better option: study the C++ idiomatic input/output streaming system. Hint: `printf`/`scanf` is not the way to go but `std::cin`/`std::cout` is.

Next, get the habit of proper code style and formatting: that would save you many hours of debugging (or even years of wasteful work).

Comment: can u please suggest me an alternate method to get proper input

Comment: @AnmølSingh please see the updates.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault may be due to the non-standard VLA.
you should try something like this:

```
int quantity_employees = 0;
int quantity_requests = 0;
std::vector<int> phone_numbers;
std::cin >> quantity_employees >> quantity_requests;
for (int i = 0; i < quantity_employees; ++i)
{
    int phone = 0;
    std::cin >> phone;
    phone_numbers.push_back(phone);
}
```

Comment: There is another obvious reason to crash with segfault.